# Inverting a colormap in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to obtain an inverted version of a given colormap to use in the colorbar of a plot.

The code below achieves this specifically for the blackwhite colormap. However, I  was looking for a more general method which would only require the name of the colormap to be inverted.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[colorbar, colormap={}{ gray(0cm)=(1); gray(1cm)=(0);}]
\addplot[mesh,thick] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[colorbar, colormap={}{ gray(0cm)=(0); gray(1cm)=(1);}]
\addplot[mesh,thick] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I understand your question correctly. You could define a new colormap named {<nameINV>} via colormap={<name>}{<color specification>} in pgfplotsset{...} and activate it by using colormap name=<nameINV>. See pages 87-88 in PGFPLOTS for detail.

Comment: `colormap={<name>}{<color specification>}` is used in the example above, but this has the inconvenience of having to manually define the colour specification. I was looking for something that would provide a general solution for inverting any existing colormap. For example, in Matlab, this is achieved by `flipud(colormap)`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### EDIT

Recent versions of pgfplots allow to answer the question in simpler form without resorting to custom macro coding. Here is the answer based on a recent version of `pgfplots`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    %colormap={X}{ gray(0cm)=(1); gray(1cm)=(0);},
    colormap/winter,
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[colorbar]
\addplot[mesh,thick] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[colorbar,
    colormap={reverse winter}{
        indices of colormap={
            \pgfplotscolormaplastindexof{winter},...,0 of winter}
    },
]
\addplot[mesh,thick] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Details about this approach can be found in the pgfplots manual, subsection "Building Colormaps based on other Colormaps".

[image]

---

### This here is the original answer

One could write such a utility macro as follows.

Note that this comes without any warranty, i.e. if the internals might change sometime, this will break (although it is unlikely that they will change soon).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}

\makeatletter
\def\customrevertcolormap#1{%
    \pgfplotsarraycopy{pgfpl@cm@#1}\to{custom@COPY}%
    \c@pgf@counta=0
    \c@pgf@countb=\pgfplotsarraysizeof{custom@COPY}\relax
    \c@pgf@countd=\c@pgf@countb
    \advance\c@pgf@countd by-1 %
    \pgfutil@loop
    \ifnum\c@pgf@counta<\c@pgf@countb
        \pgfplotsarrayselect{\c@pgf@counta}\of{custom@COPY}\to\pgfplots@loc@TMPa
        \pgfplotsarrayletentry\c@pgf@countd\of{pgfpl@cm@#1}=\pgfplots@loc@TMPa
        \advance\c@pgf@counta by1 %
        \advance\c@pgf@countd by-1 %
    \pgfutil@repeat
%\pgfplots@colormap@showdebuginfofor{#1}%
}%

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    %colormap={X}{ gray(0cm)=(1); gray(1cm)=(0);},
    colormap/winter,
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[colorbar]
\addplot[mesh,thick] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%\customrevertcolormap{X}
%\customrevertcolormap{jet}
\customrevertcolormap{winter}
\begin{axis}[colorbar]
\addplot[mesh,thick] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This only seems to work for the colormap `hot`. For other colormaps, say `winter`, the macro fails, probably because `\pgfplotscolormapassertexists{winter}` gives an undefined error. Any ideas?

Comment: The color maps need to be defined when you invoke the command. In my example, you can include the `X` colormap by uncommenting the associated lines. You can also say `colormap/winter` right where the `X` colormap is currently uncommented - that will work.

Comment: Using a key such as `colormap/winter` would be better than having to manually define each colormap, but I can't get it to work. Could you please update the example for this case?

Comment: see my edit. Note the use of `\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}`

Comment: How can I set up the colormap globally, to reuse it in multiple graphics?