# Switching Colors In Graph

Tags: pgfplots

Is there anyway I can switch the colors on this graph? Right now, the lower values are blue, and the higher values are red. Is there an easy way to do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={60}{30}]
    \addplot3 [
    mesh,
    z buffer=sort,
    samples=20,
    domain=-1:0,
    y domain=0:2*pi,
    ] (
    {sqrt(1-x^2) * cos(deg(y))},
    {sqrt( 1-x^2 ) * sin(deg(y))},
    x
    );
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Based off [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141338/128068). The colormap is called `hot`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15} % ADDED
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps} % ADDED
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{colormap/hot} % ADDED
\begin{axis}[view={60}{30},colormap={reverse hot}{indices of colormap={\pgfplotscolormaplastindexof{hot},...,0 of hot}}] % ADDED
    \addplot3 [
    mesh,
    z buffer=sort,
    samples=20,
    domain=-1:0,
    y domain=0:2*pi,
    ] (
    {sqrt(1-x^2) * cos(deg(y))},
    {sqrt( 1-x^2 ) * sin(deg(y))},
    x
    );
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Myles answer is already very elegant and short, but arguably it is even shorter just to reverse `point meta` from the default `z` to `-z`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={60}{30}]
    \addplot3 [
    mesh,
    z buffer=sort,
    samples=20,
    domain=-1:0,
    y domain=0:2*pi,point meta=-z
    ] (
    {sqrt(1-x^2) * cos(deg(y))},
    {sqrt( 1-x^2 ) * sin(deg(y))},
    x
    );
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]